# How to make a dataframe reactive in Shiny App?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I would like to create an interactive graph in a **Shiny App** with **ggplot2**. But I don't know how to make my dataframe reactive. Can you help me? Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)

payerne_temp <- read_csv('payerne_temp.csv')

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Evolution des températures"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "annee",
        label = "Sélectionnez une année",
        choices = c(
          "1972" = "y1972",
          "1973" = "y1973",
          "1974" = "y1974",
          "1975" = "y1975",
          "1976" = "y1976",
          "1977" = "y1977",
          "1978" = "y1978",
          "1979" = "y1979",
          "1980" = "y1980",
          "1981" = "y1981"
        ),
        selected = "1972",
        multiple = FALSE
      ),
      hr(),
      helpText("Source: Météosuisse")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("temperaturesPlot")
    )

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$temperaturesPlot <- renderPlot({

    payerne_temp$mois = factor(payerne_temp$mois, levels = c('janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin', 'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre'))

    ggplot(payerne_temp, aes(x = mois, group = 1)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = input$annee), color = "blue") +
      geom_line(aes(y = moy_1972_2021), color = "red")

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My goal is to use **input$annee** to select a specific column of my dataframe named **payerne_temp** to draw a plot.

Comment: Use **aes_string** instead of **aes**.

Comment: try `.data[[input$annee]]` (same solution given by @StéphaneLaurent, just different form). Can't test, your code is not reproducible.

Comment: Yeah, that works too! Both answers are perfect! Thx!